# Fixed slideToggle in table row inside another slideToggle (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, slidetoggle

I have a problem when I try to use `slideToggle` inside another `slideToggle` in a table row with jQuery.

It works, but when I close the child `slideToggle`, it starts to appear in a parent `slideToggle`.

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4vga7s87/4/) to understand.

1. Open the first `slideToggle`
2. Close the 3 `slideToggle` that just appear
3. Close the first `slideToggle`

And look: The 3 closed `slideToggle`s appear here?

I really need your help...!

Code from example here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header1').nextUntil('.header1').slideToggle(100, function(){
    });

    $('.rowClic1').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr.header1').slideToggle(100, function(){
        });
    });

    $('.rowClic2').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr.header2').slideToggle(100, function(){
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.tH {
    background-color : #fbc112;
}

.tB {
    background-color : #976eb3;
}

.tC {
    background-color : #c7d6de;
}

.tD {
    background-color : #96a4ac;
}

.rowClic1, .rowClic2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr class="tH">
              <th>HEAD A</th>
              <th>HEAD B</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <!-- 1 -->
          <tr class="tB header1">
              <td class=" rowClic1">Clic here to open first Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1.1 -->
          <tr class="tD header2">
              <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to close/open second Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tD">
              <td></td>
              <td>stay open in header1 when header2 is close :( </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1.2 -->
          <tr class="tC header2">
              <td class="rowClic2"> Clic here to close/open second Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tC">
              <td></td>
              <td>stay open in header1 when header2 is close :( </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1.3 -->
          <tr class="tD header2">
              <td class="rowClic2">CClic here to close/open second Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="tD">
              <td></td>
              <td>stay open in header1 when header2 is close :( </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that after you `.slideToggle()` the parent, `.hide()` all of the children in the callback of the parent `.slideToggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header1').nextUntil('.header1').slideToggle(100);

    $('.rowClic1').click(function(){
        //This is what we're going to toggle:
        var togglable = $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr.header1');
        //Toggle togglable:
        togglable.slideToggle(100, function() {
            //Close all of the child slideToggles after toggling the parent:
            $(".rowClic2").each(function() {
                $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr.header2').hide();
            });
        });
    });

    $('.rowClic2').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr.header2').slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

```css
.tH {
    background-color : #fbc112;
}

.tB {
    background-color : #976eb3;
}

.tC {
    background-color : #c7d6de;
}

.tD {
    background-color : #96a4ac;
}

.rowClic1, .rowClic2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr class="tH">
              <th>HEAD A</th>
              <th>HEAD B</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <!-- 1 -->
          <tr class="tB header1">
              <td class=" rowClic1">Clic here to open first Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1.1 -->
          <tr class="tD header2">
              <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to close/open second Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tD">
              <td></td>
              <td>stay open in header1 when header2 is close :( </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1.2 -->
          <tr class="tC header2">
              <td class="rowClic2"> Clic here to close/open second Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tC">
              <td></td>
              <td>stay open in header1 when header2 is close :( </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1.3 -->
          <tr class="tD header2">
              <td class="rowClic2">CClic here to close/open second Row </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="tD">
              <td></td>
              <td>stay open in header1 when header2 is close :( </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's work in this case. But i need to have a lot of "header1" (from database). So i need to use a classe. When a try to add some headers : header3 with 3.1.., header4 with 4.1... it start to bug again :(

Comment: I realy don't understand why the parent toglle show hidden element ???? Elements are toggle again ?

Comment: Last thing, i need to have every toggle close, doesn't work with this solution :((((

Comment: I don't use jQuery that much, but it seems that here, you're toggling hidden elements, which makes it shown. This means that whenever you hide a parent `slideToggle`, just make sure you show all of the children so that when you toggle it, all of the children are hidden, too. This can easily be generalized to different levels like `header3` and `header4`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to have every toggle close"?

Comment: All children toggle have to be close when we arrived the first time.

Comment: When this code snippet is first loaded or refreshed, there are no open child `slideToggle`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87601/discussion-between-mart-mars-and-noble-mushtak).

Answer (score 1):

So after a big help from Noble Mushtak, I found the solution.

SOLUTION:
It was just my selector. It was wrong because when I toggle parents, they also toggle children and vice versa : `$(this).parent().nextUntil(...`

So I made multiple `<tbody>`s in my table. Parent toggle the `<tbody>`s and children continue to toggles rows.

Sorry about my English and the fixed code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4vga7s87/12/).

Thanks again for your time, Noble Mushtak!!

The code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Close all toggle */
    $('.header2').nextUntil('.header2').slideToggle(100);
    $('.bdBody').slideToggle(100);

    $('.rowClic1').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().next('.bdBody').slideToggle(100);
    });

    $('.rowClic2').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr.header2').slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

```css
.tH {
    background-color : #fbc112;
}

.tB {
    background-color : #976eb3;
}

.tC {
    background-color : #c7d6de;
}

.tD {
    background-color : #96a4ac;
}

.rowClic1, .rowClic2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tH">
            <th>HEAD A</th>
            <th>HEAD B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <tr class="tB header1">
            <td class=" rowClic1">Clic here to close/open first Row</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="bdBody">
        <!-- 1.1 -->
        <tr class="tD header2">
            <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to open children Row </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tD">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1.2 -->
        <tr class="tC header2">
            <td class="rowClic2"> Clic here to open children Row</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1.3 -->
        <tr class="tD header2">
            <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to open children Row</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tD">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

     <tbody>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <tr class="tB header1">
            <td class=" rowClic1">Clic here to open first Row </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="bdBody">
        <!-- 2.1 -->
        <tr class="tD header2">
            <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to open children Row</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tD">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2.2 -->
        <tr class="tC header2">
            <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to open children Row</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2.3 -->
        <tr class="tD header2">
            <td class="rowClic2">Clic here to open children Row</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tD">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="tC">
            <td></td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great to know that you found your solution and glad I could help!